# Django How to get a queryset from a queryset in template

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I want to filter a queryset that depends on another queryset that already depends on another queryset

My models.py

```
class Escola(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    nome = models.CharField(db_column='Nome', max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)

class Inscrio(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    escolaid = models.ForeignKey(Escola, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='EscolaID', blank=True, null=True)

class Utilizador(AbstractBaseUser)
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    inscriçãoid = models.ForeignKey(Inscrio, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='InscriçãoID', blank=True, null=True)
```

My views.py

```
def view_forms(request):
   return render(request, 
                 "main/view_forms.html", 
                 {"escolas": Escola.objects.all(),
                 })
```

I am doing

```
{% for escola in escolas %}
   {% for inscrio in escola.inscrio_set.all %}
        {% for utilizador in inscrio.utilizador_set.all %}
            <tr>
            <td><center>{{inscrio.id}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{escola.nome}}</center></td>
            <td><center>{{utilizador.id}}</center></td> 
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

I am currently trying to get the Inscrio data from Escola.
But when I try to get the Utlizador data from the Inscrio I get nothing.

How can I do this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please can you show your View.

Comment: yes @LewisHepburn

Comment: See my answer Arthur. Thanks.

Comment: That didnt work, thanks btw

Comment: Is this the exact model structure that you are facing issue with? Also can you check the DB if there is any data?

Answer (score 0):

`Escola.objects.all` method is not executed and is passed into the template as a method.

To fix this, add Parentheses to the end. `Escola.objects.all()`

Comment: that didnt resolve. I still cant get Utilizador objects

Answer (score 0):

If you are extending `AbstractBaseUser` then you should provide `USERNAME_FIELD`.

Here `Utlizador` doesn't save any record due to this error so correct as below

```
class Utilizador(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.AutoField(db_column='ID', primary_key=True)
    inscriçãoid = models.ForeignKey(Inscrio, models.DO_NOTHING, db_column='InscriçãoID', blank=True, null=True)
    username = None
    email = models.EmailField('email address', unique=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = []
```

Comment: that didnt resolve. I still cant get Utilizador objects